# Assign pseduo class with JS?

Tags: javascript

I have created a form and with JS, if the value is " " or null, the bottom-border-color is changed to red. With input::placeholder {red} the text changes to red. Im trying to apply this if the value is " " or null. Is there a way to add this logic to my current JS code? Any tips are greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  if (nameValue.value === "" || nameValue.value == null) {
    nameError.innerText = "Please add your name!";
    inputs[1].classList.add("invalid");
  } else {
    nameError.innerText = "";
  }
  if (companyValue.value === "" || companyValue.value == null) {
    companyError.innerText = "Please add your companys name!";
    inputs[2].classList.add("invalid");
  } else {
    companyError.innerText = "";
  }
  if (titleValue.value === "" || titleValue.value == null) {
    titleError.innerText = "Please add your title!";
    inputs[3].classList.add("invalid");
  } else {
    titleError.innerText = "";
  }
  if (messageValue.value === "" || messageValue.value == null) {
    messageError.innerText = "Please leave a message!";
    inputs[4].classList.add("invalid");
  } else {
    messageError.innerText = "";
  }
  if (emailValue.value === "" || emailValue == null) {
    emailError.innerText = "Please add your email!";
    inputs[5].classList.add("invalid");
  } else {
    emailError.innerText = "";
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

[image: current display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a parent class to affect and adjust your rules accordingly

```js
function showDemo() {
document.querySelector('input[name="test"]').classList.toggle('invalid');
}
```

```css
input{
padding:5px;
width:70%;
}

::placeholder{
color:#ccc;
}

.invalid::placeholder{
color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div class='form-control'>
<input name='test' placeholder="Don't type anything in here, just click the button"/>
</div>

<button onclick='showDemo()'>Test this (toggle) </button>
```

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate you Kinglish.